# Can "See through" objects in openGL

Tags: opengl

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, I'm only rendering a few simple primitive QUADS.
The red is meant to be in front of the yellow.

The yellow always goes in-front of the red, even when it's behind it.

Is this a bug or simply me seeing the cube wrongly?

Comment: As Chen says - by default what is rendered last is on top of previously rendered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turn the depth buffer and depth test on, or OpenGL would draw what is latter on the top.

> Your application needs to do at least the following to get depth buffering to work:
>
> Ask for a depth buffer when you create your window.
>
> Place a call to glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST) in your program's initialization routine, after a context is created and made current.
>
> Ensure that your zNear and zFar clipping planes are set correctly and in a way that provides adequate depth buffer precision.
>
> Pass GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT as a parameter to glClear, typically bitwise OR'd with other values such as GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT.

See here http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I simply had to use this in the initialization: glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Comment: @Deza: This is not a initialization. It's a state being set. Speak with me: OpenGL state are not one-time-initializers, you always set them with every drawing iteration the way you need it.

Comment: @Deza agreed with @datenwolf. If you have any spare time, go reading the book `OpenGL Programming Guide`. In its chapter 1 it introduces the concept that `"OpenGL as a State Machine"`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get on the right track. There's also a nice checklist for getting the depth buffer to work here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer

For me, I had to call `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)` prior to my `glClear` call. If you use toolkits such as SFML or Qt for context creation, they will often disable the depth buffer by default, so It will also help to check the documentation of your toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it was unrelated to the depth buffer, although I did see some change for the better when I enabled that. It had to do with the blend functions used which combined pixel intensities at the last step of rendering. So I had to turn off glBlendFunc()